# Date string format

Tags: javascript, html, строки, frontend, format

имеются данные формата:

```
var dateString = "YYYY-MM-DD"; //string
```

в view нужен формат Mmm DD, YYYY (прим: "Nov 07, 2015").
Подскажите варианты, как можно отформатировать строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое близкое, что вы можете получить без особых страданий, это *Wed Apr 06 2016* при помощи вызова `(new Date('2016-04-06')).toDateString()`.

Если этот формат вас не устроит, рекомендую не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться библиотекой [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Спасибо, через moment.js и сделал =)